# Rails - how to reference namespaced table attributes in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, nested-attributes

I am trying to learn how to use namespaces in my Rails 5 app.

I have an organisation model and I have also made a series of nested models under the folder name "stance". One of those models is called overview.

The associations are:

Organisation.rb

```
has_one :overview, class_name: Stance::Overview
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :overview,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Stance::Overview

```
class Stance::Overview < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :organisation, inverse_of: :overview
```

My controllers for stance resources are nested under a folder called stance.

My routes are:

```
namespace :stance do
    resources :overviews
    end
```

In my stance view partial, I am trying to render the attributes from the overview table.

I have tried:

```
<p><%= @overview.internal_explanation %></p>
<p><%= @stance_overview.internal_explanation %></p>
<p><%= @stance.overview.internal_explanation %></p>
<p><%= @stance::overview.internal_explanation %></p>
```

I want to display this partial in my organisation show. I am trying to do that with:

```
<%= render 'stance/overviews/internal', overview: @overview %>
```

But I can't figure out how to access the overview table. Do I need to add a reference to 'stance' in the associations?

I can see that in the console I need to write:

```
o = Stance::Overview.create(internal_explanation: "test") 
o = Stance::Overview.first
```

but I can't see how to use that in the code itself.

I can see in the console that there is a record for this attribute.

The name of the table in the schema is "stance_overview".

My organisation controller has:

```
class OrganisationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_organisation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
    @organisations = Organisation.all

  end

  def show

  end

  def new
    @organisation = Organisation.new
    @organisation.build_overview

  end

  def edit
    @organisation.build_overview unless @organisation.overview
  end

  def create
    @organisation = Organisation.new(organisation_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @organisation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @organisation, notice: 'Organisation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @organisation }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @organisation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @organisation.update(organisation_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @organisation, notice: 'Organisation was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @organisation }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @organisation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @organisation.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to organisations_url, notice: 'Organisation was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end




private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_organisation
      @organisation = Organisation.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def organisation_params
      params.fetch(:organisation, {}).permit(:title,  :comment,
        overview_attributes: [:internal_explanation, :external_explanation ]

        )
    end


end
```

I have also tried defining the strong params for organisation as:

```
 stance_overview_attributes: [:internal_explanation, :external_explanation ]
```

I keep getting an error that says:

```
undefined method `internal_explanation' for nil:NilClass
```

Can anyone refer me to materials to help me learn how to use namespaces in my app. I am trying to understand the fundamentals of this so that I can bank some knowledge. I am finding things through trial and error but not understanding what's actually required (although in this case, none of my attempts are working out).

Comment: where are you setting `@overview`? It appears to be nil at runtime.

Comment: `@stance.overview.internal_explanation` this should be the correct one for showing a value from the relevant associated overview (if there is one). but if you use this: `<%= render 'stance/overviews/internal', overview: @overview %>` then that local variable means you've passed in the variable `overview` (which is set to the value that was previously in the `@overview` variable (if any)) so you could just use that directly like this: `overview.internal_explanation` but if there was nothing in `@overview` then that won't work either and maybe you need to pass in: `overview: @stance.overview`

Comment: Thanks @TarynEast - one day I'll figure out how to think this through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `Overview` model(table) when you working not in `Stance` namespace you have to use `Stance::Overview`. If working for example in a controller that in `Stance` namespace you can use just `Overview` for access.

To get access from the relation you don't need any additional notation just `@organisation.overview`.

If I understand correctly in you case you have to declare your partial as

`<%= render 'stance/overviews/internal', overview: @organisation.overview %>`

and in the partial you have to use `overview` without `@`.